# Timezone offset with nodejs server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime

I have a `nodejs` application which is hosted in `IST` Timezone server. The application has a configuration to accept `timezone` from user (Pacific Daylight Time). So based on the user `timezone` I need to display data to him. But when I fetch `timezone` for particular user in server to retrieve some statistics data in server, even though proper `timezone` is fetched it still returns `Date()` relating to the server and not according to user preferred `timezone`. Below is the piece of code am following:

```
var offset=-8; //(Pacific Daylight Time)
var d = new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000);
```

The above `var d` will still have server timezone captured and fetches data based on server `timezone`. **How can I get the `date` relating to the `client`'s timezone preference, in server?**

Comment: Dates, of themselves, don't have a time zone, their internal time value is UTC. The system time zone is used when creating "local" dates and when writing to output using *Date.prototype.toString* and *toLocaleString*. Use UTC everywhere and your problem is solved.

Comment: @RobG using UTC means, while storing the `date` data, UTC has to be stored?

Comment: @RobG.. I've also read that its good to take preferences from `client` regarding `timezone` and store it. Then probably there should be a way to fetch the date with respect to his preference right?

Comment: If you are storing their preferred time zone as a preference, then yes, apply it at the server and send a string to the client noting the time zone used. But then they will get that time zone regardless of the time zone of their host system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have stored the user's preferred time zone offset in your server, then you can create a date and time for that time zone based on the current system time of any system.

The Date internal time value is UTC, so for any Date, you can adjust the time value by the offset, then use UTC methods to output the require values in the desired format and append the time zone.

However, it's very much simpler to always work in UTC and let the host system generate date values based on system settings.

```js
/* Given a Date, return an ISO 8601 formatted date and time string
** for a particular time zone.
** @param {number} offset - offset in minutes +east, -west
** @param {Date} d - date to use, default is now
** @returns {string} ISO 8601 formatted string for supplied time zone offset
*/
function dateForTimezone(offset, d) {

  // Copy date if supplied or use current
  d = d? new Date(+d) : new Date();

  // Use supplied offset or system
  offset = offset || -d.getTimezoneOffset();
  // Prepare offset values
  var offSign = offset < 0? '-' : '+'; 
  offset = Math.abs(offset);
  var offHours = ('0' + (offset/60 | 0)).slice(-2);
  var offMins  = ('0' + (offset % 60)).slice(-2);

  // Apply offset to d
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() - offset);

  // Return formatted string
  return d.getUTCFullYear() + 
    '-' + ('0' + (d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + 
    '-' + ('0' + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + 
    'T' + ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + 
    ':' + ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + 
    ':' + ('0' + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2) + 
    '.' + ('000' + d.getUTCMilliseconds()).slice(-3) +
    offSign + offHours + ':' + offMins; 
  
}

document.write('Current date and time in US Pacific Daylight Time (PDT) time zone UTC-07:00 is: <br>' +
                dateForTimezone(-420,new Date()));
```

Comment: Thanks @RobG.. I will try this solution and let you asap.. :)

Comment: Note that the above will not respect daylight saving changes, hence it is better to use UTC as the host will most likely have appropriate settings and display standard or daylight saving time as appropriate for the particular date and time. The simple way for UTC is to store the string produced by *toISOString* or the time value returned by *getTime*. I prefer the second as it is universally converted to a Date correctly by all systems.

Answer (score 1):

In you server-side code `var d = new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000);` time always returned server time instead of client's timezone, because it execute on server. So you can sent client's time as string in `http` request and then convert time string into actual time. Then you will get client's timezone time. Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but then there must be some use of storing client's preferred timezone right? It is most recommended way too IMHO..